# Neo4j Java 7 Terminal Issue

Tags: java, terminal, neo4j

I'm having issues starting my neo4j instance (2.0.0 M03). I have java 7 installed as indicated in the code block below but when trying to start neo4j it apparently does not recognize this, gives and error and does not start. The terminal output is below. Any ideas on how to fix this or what exactly is going wrong? Thanks a lot.

```
Tim-Bornys-MacBook-Pro:neo4j community 2.0.0 M03 BornyTM$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)

Tim-Bornys-MacBook-Pro:neo4j community 2.0.0 M03 BornyTM$ bin/neo4j start
WARNING! You are using an unsupported version of the Java runtime. Please use Oracle(R)   Java(TM) Runtime Environment 7.
Starting Neo4j Server...WARNING: not changing user
process [88317]... waiting for server to be ready.... Failed to start within 120 seconds.
Neo4j Server may have failed to start, please check the logs.
```

Comment: Do you have any other java versions installed?

Comment: I might, but I'm not sure where. Before installing Java 7 I deleted the contents of the /Library/Java folder.

Comment: Found Java 6 virtual machine installed in System/Library/Java and was able to sort it out. Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest you add an answer in that regard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was JAVA_HOME was not set to the correct JVM. To determine where you have your instance installed you can enter the following into terminal:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7
```

This should return the location, in my case: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/

To set JAVA_HOME just export pointing towards the location like below (enter into the console):

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/
```