# Connecting Neo4j with qlikview11.2

Tags: jdbc, neo4j, qlikview

I want to connect Neo4j with qlikview11.2.
I have the JDBCConnector.dll and configured it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

But if I click on ok option, I can see in Edit script as CUSTOM CONNECT TO "Provider=JDBCConnector.dll;jdbc:neo4j://localhost:7474;XUserId=cdXLPIC;XPassword=FSfYRPD;";
Now if I go to select option it is directing to the below window which is totally unenabled.

[image]

So anyone please let me know whether the jar I have provided in the jdbc connector driver is correct and also the URL in qlikview.
Also suggest if any username and password has to be given along with the URL.

Comment: maybe this is a problem like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198816/neo4j-java-7-terminal-issue

Comment: The driver classname under "Advanced Settings" is probably missing. Set it to: org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver